# W3C Pay (Bobpay sample chrome extension) - MAC OS - Fails to redirect to chrome extension. Works on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, payment-processing

I am evaluating W3C pay Google examples by enabling the Chrome Extension from Google's example here: https://bobpay.xyz/   (Clicking "Install web payment app" on the bottom).  This installs the W3C Pay Chrome extension.

I then use their demo here: 
https://paymentrequest.show/demo/

I am able to submit a payment using the "Bobpay" extension, see below: 
[image]

... however when it comes time to redirect to the Bob pay "Account Selector" web application (the front end of the Payment Handler), I get the following error in Chrome's Developer tools:

[image]

"Aborting payment handler window "https://bobpay.xyz/pay" because of navigation to an insecure url "chrome-extension://noojglkidnpfjbincgijbaiedldjfbhh/data/shared/tpc-check.html"

It's complaining that the redirection to the chrome-extension URL scheme is insecure.

I already took both Certs from bobpay.xyz and paymentrequest.show sites, and installed them to my System keychain.  Then I trusted both SSL certs.  This didn't help.

BTW, this works on Windows, but not on MacOS  (Chrome on both).

Also:  submitting a sample credit card payment outside of the Bobpay extension works fine (by using a locally stored Credit card option, and not the Bobpay extension)  - returns tokenized card to be forwarded to payment processor.

This demo code also does not work on any other browsers, such as Firefox or Safari (unsupported on both).

In the Security panel of Chrome Developer tools, we can also see that the Chrome Extension for Bobpay is marked as "Unsecure": 
[image]

I also installed the whole thing on Localhost, created a self signed SSL cert, added it to keychain, trusted it, and ran an https-server with that cert, but I get the same issue on https://localhost:8080/bobpay as well.

Comment: Update:  Went here: chrome://flags/,  and set "Mark non-secure origins as non-secure" to DISABLED.  Security tab in Dev tools no longer shows any "Non-secure origins", however, the same error shows up in the Console.

Comment: Update:  I confirmed that it's not anything on the Frontend page of the Handler.  I stripped down that page to just a title and a simple text body.  The "navigation to an insecure URL" error is still happening, although there is nothing in the Network pane in dev tools.   (  chrome-extension://noojglkidnpfjbincgijbaiedldjfbhh/data/shared/tpc-check.html   )    "TPC" appears to stand for "Third Party Cookies".

Answer (score 0):

After verifying that the demo worked on another MacOS machine, I figured I introduced an issue trying to clone bobpay and deploy it on localhost under another name.  The two payment handlers were somehow trampling over each other, when redirecting to the Frontend Handler page.

I ended up removing all Chrome files in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome, clearing all Chrome settings (reset to default), and re-installing Chrome.  This cleaned out all extensions, cached data, and service workers under Dev Console --> Application.   I am now able to proceed without errors.